# AngularJS export html to pdf with css

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pdf-generation, npm

I have a task where I need to export the html to pdf. Where the pdf should have the same design as it has in browser. Basically I need the css should also work in pdf file. Am using angularjs for front end. But I have not found any use full module or any js library which supports my requirement. I also need to update AngularJS scope variables values in pdf. I found one http://pdfmake.org/#/ but it only supports some predefined css attributes. Please provide some suggestion if there is some npm module or any js library which render the html to pdf with css. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a fully featured JavaScript solution, which can convert HTML/CSS to PDF on client side. It makes sense to take a look to server-side solutions - there are many available.

In an "hybrid" scenario on client side you'd need to populate a HTML/CSS template with variable values, send the resulting HTML/CSS doc to the server side and to receive back a generated PDF.

In the case it is not important anymore, if the converter is written in JavaScript. You may use a standalone native applications, utilize print/PDF output subsystem of WebKit (i.e. [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org)) or it can be, for example, a Java module deployed to your application server (i.e. [PD4ML](http://pd4ml.com)).